# How I can add my PHP code in to code snippet?

Tags: discussion, support, languages, stack-snippets

When I asked a question on Stack Overflow the other users replied me to add a live demo. But my code contains a PHP part also, and I can't see a method to add codes other than HTML, CSS and JavaScript in a code snippet. Is it possible to add demonstration of any other languages in a code snippet? If so, how is it possible?

Comment: i think they might be referring to making a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). otherwise there are [third](https://repl.it/) [party](http://sqlfiddle.com/) sites not affiliated with Stack Exchange where you can put your code up as demos.

Comment: This should be asked on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: @patrick i will ask this on meta stack over flow

Comment: Huh? Off topic? This is about Stack Snippets, which is on multiple sites on the network (even on this very site!) -- I think this is on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Code snippets are a cool way to add runnable examples to the site, but you really don't have to use them (especially for languages they do not support). Just paste your code as text and indent it with four spaces. E.g.:

```php
echo('I am a code snippet!');
```

If your post is tagged properly (or if you specify the language explicitly, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)), you'll even get some neat syntax highlighting.